# How to renew intermediate Sub CA certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

The intermediate sub-CA certificate is expiring mid 2023 and the root CA certificate is expiring in 2028.  How to renew the intermediate Sub CA? Or is it auto-renewed? If Yes then how and where do I go to find out if it is auto-renewed?

Comment: This question is missing context. Is this about your own CA - you need to renew it yourself, follow the documentation of whatever system you use to manage your PKI. If this is about a CA managed by others - they will hopefully renew the intermediate CA.

Comment: Yes, this is about my organization CA. where can I find the documentation to manage and renew the intermediate Sub CA?

Comment: Find out what system you are using to manage your CA. Then find out where the documentation for this system is - maybe contact your vendor for support. This is not a product support site and it is even impossible to help since the product is unknown.